# Browser still pending connection of my long time script

Tags: php

A user recommended this code
http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php
to close connection and continue my script.

The problem is that in Chrome developer tools I still see my xhr request "pending" and a long time after it is ended and "Finish" time is long. I don't want it. I want see Status 200 after I close connection by php documentation.
How to do it?

Comment: Although this is a duplicate question, the answers found on stackoverflow are old ~2009 and don't seem to be working for me either. Please review it before marking as duplicate.

Comment: Now I found function fastcgi_finish_request();. Did you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer after few weeks which works for me.

```
if(function_exists('fastcgi_finish_request')) {
    fastcgi_finish_request();
}
```